# File could not be renamed, folder name conflicts with filename in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, files, filemanager, rename

As the title says, my fresh, updated Ubuntu 13.10 install, presents a conflict with files and folders of the same name, in the same location, as shown below

[image: this image:]

Comment: This isn't a question.  You can't have two things with the same name in the same place, so you will have to name the new file something else.

Comment: It's not like it's two files, or two folders. In this case I'm trying to give the file the same name as a folder, and surely this is allowed in most os.

Comment: Nope.. not allowed in any OS that I know of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux every thing is file.
So even if you are creating a folder, Linux treats it like a file internally. So here you can'n rename with a name which you have already given to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a folder named Test, so the name is already taken. That is why you are seeing error. Since Ubuntu is case sensitive you can use test if you want.